# If $f \in A(D)$, is $f'$ continuous in $\overline D$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $D$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb C$ and let $A(D)$ be the [disk algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_algebra), i.e the algebra of analytic functions in $D$ that are continuous in $\overline D$.

My question is:

> If $f \in A(D)$, is $f'$ continuous in $\overline D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider
$$
f(z)=(1-z)\log(1-z)\quad\text{or}\quad f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n!}}{n^2}.
$$